# Featured Image Thumbnail Creation

Tags: functions, images

What function or script creates the hard-cropped feature image when a post is saved? Regardless if I stipulate a size when saving the featured image in the media library (like the medium size),  a new image is created upon saving the post.

Answer (score 1):

The image isn't created on *save*, but rather on *upload*. The same process that creates the "thumbnail", "medium", and "large" size images also creates any other image sizes defined via `add_image_size()`.